# Optimal Poincare constant (with constraints)

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, functional-inequalities

Given any integrable function $f\, \colon \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb R$, it is relative easy to show that the best constant for which the following Poincar'e-type inequality $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} f^2\,\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x \leq C\,\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} |f'|^2\,\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{1}$$ holds is $C = 4$. Indeed, we can prove $(1)$ by writing $f(x) = -\int_{x}^\infty f'(y)\,\mathrm{d} y$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz several times. The optimality of the constant $4$ can be seen by taking $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda\,x}$ for $\lambda > 1/2$ and then sending $\lambda \to 1/2$. However, suppose we have further constraints on $f$ prescribed by $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0,\quad\text{and}\quad \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} x\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0. \tag{2} $$ How can we "sharpen" (or refine) the Poincare constant with the help of these additional restrictions? Clearly, the argument without $(2)$ relies purely on the fundamental theorem of calculus and the basic Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I am stuck at the possibility of incorporating $(2)$ into the argument in order to refine the constant $C$ appearing in $(1)$. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

We can handle this with Calculus of Variations. Defining

$$
L(f,f',x) = \left(f^2-C(f')^2\right)e^x
$$

and solving

$$
\max J(f,C)= \max\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}\left(L(f,f',x) + \lambda_1f + \lambda_2xf\right) dx
$$

with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ Lagrange multipliers.

NOTE

Let us consider the simpler problem

$$
\max J(f,C)= \max\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}\left(f^2-C(f')^2\right)e^x dx
$$

The Euler-Lagrange equation gives the stationary condition
$$
Cf''+Cf'+f=0
$$

with solution

$$
f = c_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{C-4}}{\sqrt{C}}\right) x}+c_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{C-4}}{\sqrt{C}}-1\right) x}
$$

As $f$ should be integrable on $\mathbb{R}^+$ , $c_2=0$ so we follow with

$$
f =  c_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{C-4}}{\sqrt{C}}\right) x}
$$

and now substituting this function on $J(f,C)$ we get

$$
J(f,C)=\frac{\left(4-C-\sqrt{C-4} \sqrt{C}\right) c_1{}^2}{2 \sqrt{\frac{C-4}{C}}}=-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{C}\sqrt{C-4}+C \right)c_1^2
$$

and $\max J(f,C)=\lim_{C\to 4}J(f,C) = -2c_1^2\le 0$.

NOTE

Regarding the full problem, as the stationary condition gives the function

$$
f = c_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{\frac{C-4}{C}}+1\right) x}-\frac{1}{2} e^{-x} (\lambda_2 (C+x)+\lambda_1)
$$

the restrictions gives us

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} f dx = \frac{1}{2} \left(c_1C -\sqrt{C-4} \sqrt{C} c_1-(C+1) \lambda_2-\lambda_1\right)=0
$$

and

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} x f dx = \frac{4 c_1}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{C-4}{C}}+1\right)^2}-\frac{1}{2} (C+2) \lambda_2-\frac{\lambda_1}{2}=0
$$

Solving for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ we get

$$
\cases{
\lambda_1 = \frac{4 \sqrt{C} \left(-C^{3/2}+\sqrt{C-4} C+2 \sqrt{C-4}\right) c_1}{\left(\sqrt{C-4}+\sqrt{C}\right)^2}\\
\lambda_2 = -\frac{4 \left(\sqrt{\frac{C-4}{C}}-1\right)
   c_1}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{C-4}{C}}+1\right)^2}
}
$$

and after substitution into $J(f,C,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ it gives

$$
J(f,C,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = -\frac{128 \left(\sqrt{C-4}+5 \sqrt{C}\right) \sqrt{C} c_1{}^2}{\left(\sqrt{C-4}+\sqrt{C}\right)^8}
$$

Here $J(f,C,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) \le 0 $ and its maximum occours as $C\rightarrow \infty$. Also as $C\rightarrow \infty$ we have $\lambda_1\rightarrow 0$ and $\lambda_2\rightarrow 0$ so the conclusion is that the problem has not solution as formulated. Does not exists such $C$.

Comment: Thanks! I probably need to work on the Euler-Lagrange equation associated with this minimization problem, but I am not sure right now if explicit solution of the resulting E-L equation is obtainable. I will update my comments later. By the way, in your formulation $C$ can take as large as I want?

Comment: According to my estimations $C\ge 4$.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do it for myself to facilitate my understanding.

Comment: Actually I am a little bit concerned about your definition of $L(f,f',x)$. Should I define $L(f,f,x')$ as $\frac{f^2}{(f')^2}$ instead?

Comment: Please. See the attached note to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! May I know how does the last step follows from the expression of $J(f,C)$? i.e., why the maximum of $J(f,C)$ is achieved when we send $C \to 4$?

Comment: Included a step more in the calculation of $J(f,C)$.

Comment: Thanks. But for the "true" maximization problem the E-L equation should be $2\,(f + C\,f' + C\,f'')\,\mathrm{e}^x + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2\, x = 0$ right? Does this ODE admits a explicit solution at all?

Comment: We know that $f+Cf'+Cf''=-\frac 12(\lambda_1+\lambda_2 x)e^{-x}$ is lineal, so we need a particular solution to solve the complete ODE. The homogeneous solution we already know. A particular solution is $f_p = -\frac 12(\lambda_1+\lambda_2(C+x))e^{-x}$.

Comment: Thanks! Plugging back into the expression of $J(f,C)$ now has three parameters to be optimized (i.e., $C$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$), is it possible to solve the resulting "optimization problem" explicitly?

Comment: Now we need to determine the stationary points,determining the solution for $\nabla_{C,\lambda_1,\lambda_2} J(f,C,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=0$

Comment: The computation is really a messy by hand and I am not sure if everything in the end admits a "simple and nice" answer. But anyhow thanks for this guidance, I will accept this (partial) answer.

Comment: Yes. The stationary conditions can be handled perhaps with a symbolic processor in the hope it would give us a numeric (approximate) solution.

Comment: Please. See final attached note.

Comment: Thanks! It is however a bit weird that "adding more constraints" does not sharpen the "best constant"... I will try to check some parts of the computations you give here.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think your solutions/formulas for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are correct (I agree with the linear system for these variables). For instance, for $\lambda_2$, my computation yields $\lambda_2 = \frac{c_1\left(8 + (\sqrt{C} + \sqrt{C-4})^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{C-4}{C}} - 1\right)\right)}{\left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{C-4}{C}}\right)^2}$.

Comment: I checked out my results and they seem Ok.

Comment: I somehow disagree with your formulas for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ (I gave my computations of $\lambda_2$ above), but anyhow thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!